# how to rename multiple prefix filename with one command in linux ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, filenames, rename

I have a files in a folder like this :

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   25088 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_abstraksi.doc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   15119 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_abstraksi.docx
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  146532 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_abstraksi.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  145408 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_bab1.doc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   75399 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_bab1.docx
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  193581 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_bab1.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  156672 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_bab2.doc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  101341 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_bab2.docx
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  316476 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_bab2.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  952320 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_bab3.doc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   89826 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_bab3.docx
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  399203 Nov  6  2013 108400344_2223_bab3.pdf
```

And then i want to change **"108400344_2223_"** to be **"14.04.329"** in the same time. I try almost all tutorial but it fail..so how to do this in linux ubuntu server 12.04?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

1. Since Ubuntu comes with the perl `rename` program, you could simply do

   ```
   rename 's/108400344_2223_/14.04.329_/' *
   ```
2. Shell

   ```
   for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f/108400344_2223_/14.04.329_}"; done
   ```

If the files can be in multiple sub directories, use `find`:

```
find . -name '108400344_2223_*' -exec rename 's/108400344_2223_/14.04.329_/' {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your files in some directory 'e':

```
$ ls -1 e/
108400344_2223_abstraksi.doc
108400344_2223_abstraksi.docx
108400344_2223_abstraksi.pdf
108400344_2223_bab1.doc
108400344_2223_bab1.docx
108400344_2223_bab1.pdf
108400344_2223_bab2.doc
108400344_2223_bab2.docx
108400344_2223_bab2.pdf
108400344_2223_bab3.doc
108400344_2223_bab3.docx
108400344_2223_bab3.pdf
```

You can easily use **string substitution** to rename all files from `108400344_2223_file` to `14.04.329file`

```
$ for i in e/*; do mv "$i" ${i//108400344_2223_/14.04.329}; done
```

**confirm:**

```
$ ls -11 e
14.04.329abstraksi.doc
14.04.329abstraksi.docx
14.04.329abstraksi.pdf
14.04.329bab1.doc
14.04.329bab1.docx
14.04.329bab1.pdf
14.04.329bab2.doc
14.04.329bab2.docx
14.04.329bab2.pdf
14.04.329bab3.doc
14.04.329bab3.docx
14.04.329bab3.pdf
```

Personally, I would add an underscore between the date and file:

```
$ for i in e/*; do mv "$i" ${i//108400344_2223/14.04.329}; done
```

Giving:

```
14.04.329_abstraksi.doc
14.04.329_abstraksi.docx
...
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will be helpfull

```
for k in `ls -la | awk '{print $9}'`; do mv $k 14.04.329`ls -la $k | awk -F _ '{print $3}'`; done
```

output is like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 09:46 14.04.329abstraksi.doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 09:46 14.04.329abstraksi.docx
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 09:46 14.04.329abstraksi.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 09:46 14.04.329bab1.doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 09:46 14.04.329bab1.docx
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 09:46 14.04.329bab1.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Sep 23 09:46 14.04.329bab2.doc
```

Comment: Please [never recommend parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), doubly so for parsing it with a `for` loop.